# GPG with tar.gz at the same time without the full path being packed

Tags: linux, encryption, compression, tar, gnupg

I would like to compress and encrypt a folder:

- `tar -cz "/path/to/the/folder/" | gpg --encrypt --passphrase "password"
  --recipient "mail@mail.mail" > "/destination/package.tar.gz.gpg"`

When I decrypt and uncompress, it does not only contains the "folder" that I compressed, but has the full file path: `/path/to/the/folder/[whatever]`

I prefer avoiding the usage of `cd`, the absolute paths seems more clear to me.

**How do I remove the full file path from the archive?**

Comment: see the tar  `-C dir` option to effectively cd before tarring.

Answer (score 1):

`tar` has different behavior, depending on whether you execute it from a folder not in the current path (for example, you `tar` something in `/usr/local/src/foo`, while being in your home directory `/home/alice`), where it will store the absolute path in the tar file. If you're in some folder in the path (for example, you want to tar `/usr/local/src/foo` while being in `/use/local/src`), it will use relative paths starting from the `src` directory.

If you do not want to actually change directory into the desired relative root directory, use the `-C` flag which virtually does so inside `tar`. These two are equivalent:

```
cd /path/to/the/folder; tar -cz *; cd $OLDPWD
tar -C /path/to/the/folder -cz /path/to/the/folder/
```

In case you wonder: `$OLDPWD` contains the last folder *before* `cd`ing into it.